# Rounded Corners only on one side of a Visual

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I'm trying to have a `Visual` with rounded corners. Here's the code I have:

```
auto clip = compositor->CreateGeometricClip();
auto roundedRectangle = compositor->CreateRoundedRectangleGeometry();
roundedRectangle->Size = Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float2(width, height);
roundedRectangle->CornerRadius = Windows::Foundation::Numerics::float2(10, 10);
clip->Geometry = roundedRectangle;
visual->Clip = clip;
```

This works but this creates rounded corners on all 4 corners of the visual. Is it possible to use the `Composition` APIs to achieve what I'm targetting? For reference, here's what I want the end result to look like.

[image]

and not what I have now

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionroundedrectanglegeometry.offset?view=winrt-19041) property and the `CornerRadius` property of a `CompositionRoundedRectangleGeometry` instance to gain the effect you target. The `Visual.Clip` property specifies the clipping region for the visual. When a visual is rendered, only the protion of the visual that falls inside the clipping region is displayed, while any content that extends outside the clipping region is clipped. Therefore, we could cut off a small part of the right side of the rounded rectangle by adjusting the size of `visual` and the size and offset of the `clip`.

Please check the following code as a sample:

```
auto clip = _compositor->CreateGeometricClip();
auto roundedRectangle = _compositor->CreateRoundedRectangleGeometry();
roundedRectangle->Size = float2(100, 100);
//roundedRectangle->CornerRadius = float2(20, 20);
roundedRectangle->Offset = float2(20, 0);
clip->Geometry = roundedRectangle;

//auto visual = _compositor->CreateSpriteVisual();
//visual->Brush = _compositor->CreateColorBrush(ColorHelper::FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x11, 0xFF));
visual->Size = float2(100+20, 100);
roundedRectangle->Size = visual->Size;
visual->Clip = clip;
```

The key is let the size of `visual` the same as the size of `clip`, and set a value of `Offset` property of the `clip` to make the right part of the rounded rectangle exceed the size of the `visual`. The first parameter of `Offset` property represents the left and right space between `clip` and `visual`. I set the value of `Offset` as `float2(20, 0)` to let the right part of the rounded rectangle exceed the size of the `visual`. You could adjust the value of `Offset` property based on your needs.

Comment: Thanks! This does help me achieve what I was targetting. I essentially did `visual->Size += float2(radius, 0); rr->Offset = (radius, 0); rr->size = visual->Size;` otherwise the roundedRectangle ended up clipping the visual area that it had been offset by, `radius` in this case. You could probably add that to your answer. Essentially `visual->Size` should be `= float2(100 + 20, 100)`.