# Different corner radii for a Visual's clip

Tags: css, uwp, c++-winrt, winui

I was trying to set the `Clip` on a `Visual`. The path is supposed to be a rounded rectangle with different corner radii. The [current API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionroundedrectanglegeometry.cornerradius?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionRoundedRectangleGeometry_CornerRadius) for setting the `CornerRadius` on a `RoundedRectangleGeometry` allows setting a uniform radius on all the four corners

```
auto roundedRectangle = compositor.CreateRoundedRectangleGeometry();
roundedRectangle.CornerRadius(Float2(width, height));
clip.Geometry(roundedRectangle);
visual.Clip(clip);
```

But I'm trying to align with the CSS property of [`background-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) which permits setting different corner-radius for all the 4 corners:

```
border-radius: 10px 100px 20px 30px/ 30px 20px 10px 40px;
```

leading to something with all four different elliptical corners as

[image: Different corner-radii]

So in essence, I'm seeking a way to emulate this for a `Visual`'s `Clip` property, allowing me to achieve a similar effect as the CSS property.

P.S. This is a continuing effort from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666113/rounded-corners-only-on-one-side-of-a-visual) question. This is something I've already tried but applying the same logic of offsetting the clipping `RoundedRectangle` didn't work in this case.The answer to that question won't suffice for this requirement because the rounded corner radii were the same for 2 corners (in fact all 4 corners) in that case and the suggested solution would not be adequate for all different elliptical corners. Offsetting the clipping `RoundedRectangle` won't work here because I'd need 4 different `RoundedRectangle`s and then somehow position them over the `Visual` but the `Clip` property allows only one `CompositionGeometricClip` with one `Geometry`.

I'm using the `C++/WinRT` language projection.

Answer (score 1):

Uwp app hasn’t provided such api to do this. We suggest you could implement this requirement through an image whose source is a picture of specified shape in uwp.

In addition, you could use the WinUI3 api named [RectangleClip Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.composition.rectangleclip?view=winui-3.0) to do this, which has TopLeftRadius, TopRightRadius, BottemLeftRadius, BottemRightRadius properties, so that you could set different corner-radius for 4 corners. To use this api, you need to [create a WinUI 3 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/get-started-winui3-for-desktop). Please refer to the following code.

Xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="host1" Background="red">
     
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
       var cor = Window.Current.Compositor;
        RectangleClip rectclip = cor.CreateRectangleClip();
        rectclip.Left = 40;
        rectclip.Top = 20;
        rectclip.Right = 300;
        rectclip.Bottom = 150;
        rectclip.TopLeftRadius = new System.Numerics.Vector2(5);
        rectclip.TopRightRadius = new System.Numerics.Vector2(30);
        rectclip.BottomLeftRadius = new System.Numerics.Vector2(10);
        rectclip.BottomRightRadius = new System.Numerics.Vector2(60);
        Visual visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(host1);
        visual.Clip = rectclip;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we are yet to upgrade to WinUI3 and would need some time to migrate to that which is why the UWP compatibility is still required.  Would you be able to elaborate more on the Image Source solution, if possible?

Comment: My meaning is that you could create a picture of the desired shape(4 different corner radius), then set it to the source of an image control.

Comment: Ah, that won't be possible because it's not that we have a single shape that would be fixed. The corner radius can be set to anything (programmatically/by the user) and we couldn't possibly have Images to cater to all possible radius combinations.

Comment: How about `Border` control? The `CornerRadius` property of border control could set different corner-radius for 4 corners. Then you could place control inside it, it will achieve a clip effect.

Comment: `<Border  Height="60" Width="100" CornerRadius="10,20,30,40" >
        <Image Source="/Assets/test1.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Border>`

Comment: It seems that the [`cornerRadius`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.cornerradius?view=winrt-20348) can only support *circular* radii on all the four corners. I'm looking for elliptical radii. I might be wrong. Basically [`TopLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.cornerradius.topleft?view=winrt-20348) is a `double` rather than a `Float2`

Comment: It seems that circular radii would actually work for me but unfortunately, it seems that a `Border` can only wrap around a `UIElement` and not a `Visual` as per the documentation of the [`Child`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.border.child?view=winrt-20348#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Border_Child) property. As mentioned in my question, I'm looking for something around a `Visual`. Creating a `UIElement` around a `Visual` isn't an option because there are many child `Visual`s that this needs to be applied to and creating `UIElement`s to host all would be a problem

Comment: We are consulting other engineers about your issue, there might be some delay.