# Using complex paths for CompositionClip

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt, winui, windows-composition-api, direct-composition

`Visual`s in UWP/WinUI can have a [`Clip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.visual.clip?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Composition_Visual_Clip) applied to them which is an instance of a [`CompositionClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionclip?view=winrt-19041). One of the types of `CompositionClip` is a [`GeometricClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositiongeometricclip?view=winrt-19041) which can have a [`Geometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositiongeometricclip.geometry?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionGeometricClip_Geometry) of various types derived from the [`CompositionGeometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositiongeometry?view=winrt-19041) class. I'm seeking to have a clip that has the shape of a rounded rectangle but with different elliptical corner radii as follows

[image]

This would ideally be suited for the [`CompositionRoundedRectangleGeometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionroundedrectanglegeometry?view=winrt-19041) but that class has a limitation that it supports having the same elliptical radius on *all four corners*, not allowing for different radii. So that leaves [`CompositionPathGeometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionpathgeometry?view=winrt-19041) whose [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionpathgeometry.path?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionPathGeometry_Path) is defined by a [`CompositionPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionpath?view=winrt-19041) instance. This is where I've reached a dead end.

This `CompositionPath` *implements* the [`IGeometrySource2D`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionpath?view=winrt-19041) interface. I couldn't figure out how to use this `IGeometrySource2D` interface to construct a complex path with lines and curves. Searching online led to [this](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2018/08/13/drawing-shapes-with-windows-composition-in-uwp/) article which too skirts using that interface and instead uses the classes built around [`CanvasPathGeometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/parsers/canvaspathgeometry) which is from the `Windows Community Toolkit` and, if I understand correctly, only meant for `C#` projects as per [this](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) GitHub page and won't work for me since I need something in C++.

So the questions are:

- How do we use `IGeometrySource2D` and `CompositionPath` to create complex shapes? If it's not feasible, then
- Is there any equivalent of `CanvasPathGeometry` for `C++/WinRT` language projection?

P.S. I'm aware that WinUI 3 offers [`RectangleClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.composition.rectangleclip?view=winui-3.0)(as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67685814/1851678) answer) that would work for my case but that isn't available in UWP, so that's not a feasible solution for me.

**EDIT:**

Here's an attempt using [`Win2D.UWP`](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI2/html/Introduction.htm) NuGet package, based on the suggestions/pointers shared in the comments.

```
auto visual = _compositor->CreateSpriteVisual();
visual->Size = float2(500.0f);
visual->Offset = float3(50, 50, 0);
visual->Brush = _compositor->CreateColorBrush(Colors::Red);

auto canvasPathBuilder = ref new CanvasPathBuilder(ref new CanvasDevice());
canvasPathBuilder->BeginFigure(radius.topLeft.x, 0);
canvasPathBuilder->AddLine(visual->Size.x - radius.topRight.x, 0);
canvasPathBuilder->AddArc(float2(visual->Size.x , radius.topRight.y ), radius.topRight.x, radius.topRight.y,
    0, CanvasSweepDirection::Clockwise, CanvasArcSize::Small);
canvasPathBuilder->AddLine(visual->Size.x, visual->Size.y - radius.bottomRight.y);
canvasPathBuilder->AddArc(float2(visual->Size.x - radius.bottomRight.x, visual->Size.y), radius.bottomRight.x, radius.bottomRight.y,
    0, CanvasSweepDirection::Clockwise, CanvasArcSize::Small);
canvasPathBuilder->AddLine(radius.bottomLeft.x, visual->Size.y);
canvasPathBuilder->AddArc(float2(0, visual->Size.y - radius.bottomLeft.y), radius.bottomLeft.x, radius.bottomLeft.y,
    0, CanvasSweepDirection::Clockwise, CanvasArcSize::Small);
canvasPathBuilder->AddLine(0, radius.topLeft.y);
canvasPathBuilder->AddArc(float2(radius.topLeft.x, 0), radius.topLeft.x, radius.topLeft.y,
     0, CanvasSweepDirection::Clockwise, CanvasArcSize::Small);
canvasPathBuilder->EndFigure(CanvasFigureLoop::Closed);

auto canvasGeometry = CanvasGeometry::CreatePath(canvasPathBuilder);
auto compositionPath = ref new CompositionPath(canvasGeometry);
auto pathGeometry = _compositor->CreatePathGeometry();
pathGeometry->Path = compositionPath;
visual->Clip = _compositor->CreateGeometricClip(pathGeometry);
```

This appears to work

[image: Win2DRoundedRecangle]

Now, the next step would be to work to remove the `Win2D` dependency for `CanvasPath` et al and to use `ID2D1Geometry` and other interfaces to supply the `IGeomterySource2D` since I would *prefer* *not having NuGet packages as a project dependency*.

Comment: You create a `CompositionPath` from an object that implements both `IGeometrySource2D` and `IGeometrySource2DInterop`. `IGeometrySource2DInterop.GetGeometry` asks for a Direct2D geometry (`ID2D1Geometry`) that you can implement using "regular" C/C++. In most samples you'll find this is done using Win2D (which is reserved for UWP only which a stupid design decision).

Comment: As you mentioned, maybe you could do this via CanvasPathGeometry, you could draw such shape through combining those methods, for instance, AddSrc() and AddLine() methods.

Comment: We are consulting other engineers about your issue, there might be some delay.

Comment: @SimonMourier Could you please direct me to the references/documentation for `IGeometrySource2DInterop`? I couldn't find anything much apart from scant few issues mentioning that interface.

Comment: This is the new Microsoft, all open source, but not all documented. The definition is in the Windows SDK here C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\winrt\windows.graphics.interop.h and you'll find references in Win2D: https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D/blob/master/winrt/lib/geometry/CanvasGeometry.h

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Did you get a chance to seek any suggestions from MSFT engineers on this? I've updated the answer with my attempt at using `Win2D` but I'd still prefer not to have NuGet and stick to the SDK. Is the entire implementation of `Visual->Clip` using a `CompositionPath` not possible using just the SDK APIs?