# Rounded Corners only on one side of a Visual for an older Win10 version

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

This is based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66666113/1851678) question. That question deals with a way to round only one side of a rounded rectangle. This question asks the same question but specifically for Win10 version 1803 (Build 17134). The reason is that the same functionality is required for applications running on older Win10 versions where [`Compositor.CreateGeometricClip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor.creategeometricclip?view=winrt-20348#Windows_UI_Composition_Compositor_CreateGeometricClip) isn't available and users are unwilling to update to newer versions.

So, what I thought was that instead of creating clips with the shape of rounded rectangle, I might as well create [`CompositionSpriteShape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionspriteshape?view=winrt-20348)s (wrapped within [`ShapeVisual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.shapevisual?view=winrt-20348)s) with a [`CompositionRoundedRectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionroundedrectanglegeometry?view=winrt-20348) geometry that allows uniform [`CornerRadius`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionroundedrectanglegeometry.cornerradius?view=winrt-20348#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionRoundedRectangleGeometry_CornerRadius) to be set. This works for me. So I ended up with something like.

```
auto roundedRectGeometry = compositor.CreateRoundedRectangleGeometry(); // create the geometry
roundedRectGeometry.Size(float2{x, y});
roundedGeometry.CornerRadius(float2{rx, ry}); // set the corner radius
auto shape = compositor.CreateSpriteShape(roundedRectGeometry); // create the shape
auto shapeVisual = compositor.CreateShapeVisual(); // create the ShapeVisual
shapeVisual.Shapes().Append(shape); // Wrap the shape in the ShapeVisual
```

Now this gives me a shape with rounded corners. Here I'm stuck as to how do I apply the rounding only on one edge? The answer in the linked question relies on a trick of changing the offset/size of the clip/visual. For instance, if I need to clip only on the right, I could do something like

```
roundedClipGeometry.Size(visualSize + corneradius, visualSize); // increase it's length
```

so that by increasing its length, I effectively end up clipping the right end. Similarly, the length can be increased for clipping only on the left, with the added step that it needs to be offset to the left so that the right side remains unimpacted but the left ends up getting clipped.

```
roundedRectangle.Offset(float2(-radiusWidth, 0)); // Offset to the left, so that left gets clipped
```

Given that I'm restricted to an older version, the only clip available to me is [`InsetClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.insetclip?view=winrt-20348) which clips the visual outside its offset and *doesn't provide any API to alter its size*. Changing the size of the `ShapeVisual` isn't an option too since the `InsetClip` assumes the same size. How do I go about achieving my use case of rounding only on one side with these restrictions?

Comment: Any code sample could share ?

Comment: Could you please submit feedback about this in the Feedback Hub?